# Create custom keywords and operators

Tags: bash

I would like to use a couple of other keywords instead of common operators, such as `or` for `||`.

`alias` only does such things to the command line, while I am only interested in the core syntax of bash itself.

In other languages, you can do that with a simple binding, such as in F# via `let (or) = (||)`

Comment: `||` is not a function in shell; it's built into the grammar. Take shell as it is, rather than trying to turn it into something else.

Comment: I ask for help to create my own keywords and operators. If you can help me, you are welcome. Otherwise, you have missed the point of this question.

Comment: I don't think there's a good way to do this in bash, and I don't think this is a good idea.

Comment: And I am saying you *cannot* create your own keywords and operators in shell.

Comment: (Actually, you can use aliases to replace keywords in many instances, though it's still a bad idea.)

Comment: @chepner As far as I'm aware, it's impossible for operators, however.

Comment: Right, operators like `||` are recognized by the parser, before alias expansion takes place.

Comment: This is a terrible idea, but `or () { if test $? = 0; then return 0; else "$@"; fi; }`.  It's not ideal, as you need to do `cmd1; or cmd2` instead of `cmd1 or cmd2`.

Comment: Bash doesn't let you define keywords or operators. Would you be ok with functions, like @WilliamPursell mentioned? Also could you please edit your question to include an actual question? The ambiguity is killing me :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As aliases:

```
alias and='(($?==0)) &&'
alias or='(($?==0)) ||'
alias not='!'
```

As functions:

```
and () {
    (($?==0)) && "$@"
}

or () {
    (($?==0)) || "$@"
}

not () {
    ! "$@"
}
```

Usage:

```
$ false; and echo hello
$ true; and echo hello
hello
$ false; or echo hello
hello
$ true; or echo hello
$ not false; echo $?
0
$ not true; echo $?
1
```

These are used the same as [Fish's combiner builtins](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/tutorial.html#tut_combiners).

Comment: I hate this so much, but I won't downvote because it's what OP asked for

Comment: @Coffee to be clear I also hate it and don't see any good use for it - mostly I wanted to try it as an exercise.